# What is the standard for dealing with null values in plotting?

Tags: visualization

There's really no "standard," I assume, but how do you deal with null values when plotting data? An example of what I'm talking about is listed below:
[image]

Suppose I'm plotting data on number of toys by color. Nearly half of these toys in my database have `null` values for color. Do you guys include the toys with `null` values in your visualization? How do you address that issue? Saying "nearly half of the toys didn't have colors listed" doesn't really add much to the conversation.

Comment: Why do you ask "What is the standard" and then start your question with the assumption that there's really no "standard"?

Comment: *Saying "nearly half of the toys didn't have colors listed" doesn't really add much to the conversation.* It adds an enormous amount to the conversation in my opinion and would be a statement I would **expect** to be made in the document (if not in a note on the figure itself!) if the nulls were dropped out.

Answer (score 1):

Imo, It depends on two major factors:

- What is the purpose of the plot
- Does the `null` value indicate incompleteness (*one of the values, but unknown which one*), or does it indicate a last final option, (*like: multiple colors*)

---

Imagine if the purpose of the plot is to compare which toy colors are most popular to a particular person/group.

If `null` indicates multi-colored toys, it may be important to include the data but rename it to something more meaningful. (*Multi-colored*)

If `null` indicates that we just don't know the color data for those toys, it would probably be best to exclude that data from the plot. However, with such a large percentage, it would be good to note that "x%" were excluded from your plot because they had no color information associated with them. Perhaps purple is in such a majority because this person/group really likes purple, or maybe its because purple toys almost never made it into the `null` category for whatever reason.

---

The same line of thinking should be applied to whatever the purpose of the plot is. If the `null` values are relevant to the purpose, include them. If not, don't - and maybe take a note of how much data is excluded if it could influence the results substantially (such as this case)